# Ignoring style for a concrete tag

Tags: html, css

I have a css file for my entire site. In that css file, for example, I have the following style defined for all my reference links such as:

```
a{
   color: #333;
   padding-right: 3px;
   padding-left: 3px;
   text-decoration: underline;
   outline-width: medium;
   outline-style: none;
   outline-color: invert;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover{
   color: #333;
}
```

so all my links in my site have above styling, but there are only three links in my page that I do not want to apply this style, I mean, I want to ignore it in order to be not applied, so how to ignore style for below links?

```
   <nav id="NavigationMenu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```

Updated:

```
<div id="flagsGroup">
  <div id="flag">
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "es-ES", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/SpanishFlag.png" alt="Change page language to spanish."/></a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "ca-ES", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/CatalanFlag.png" alt="Change page language to catalan."/></a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "en-GB", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/BritishFlag.png" alt="Change page language to english."/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to escapse `"` in `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be more specific and overwrite it with the default values.

Works perfectly fine.. [**jsFiddle demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2rfU/)

**CSS**

```
#NavigationMenu #menu li > a {
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline:none;
    color:#000;
}

#NavigationMenu #menu li > a:link, 
#NavigationMenu #menu li > a:visited,
#NavigationMenu #menu li > a:active,
#NavigationMenu #menu li > a:hover{
   color: #000;
}
```

**EDIT.. based on your update:**

```
#flagsGroup #flags > a {
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
}

#flagsGroup #flags > a:link, 
#flagsGroup #flags > a:visited,
#flagsGroup #flags > a:active,
#flagsGroup #flags > a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post. And In case of the links contained within the divs flagsgroup and flag?

Comment: @JoshC overriding is not the same as exclude some elements from that rule.

Comment: @JoshC IE, what's that? :P

Comment: @Recode Yea, I know. I hate it as well. 1+ for your solution though. I like it.

Comment: @JoshC jQuery 2.x doesn't support them either, but yes, if you care about these I recommend your solution and jquery 1.x

Comment: as my version of jquery is 1.x and your solution works and you answered first, I accept yours as a solution. @Recode solution also is working on modern browsers, I have checked.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude these links with the `:not`-selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2rfU/1/

```
a:not(#menu a) {
   color: red;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

With this CSS, all links turn red aside from links in your menu.

Based on your update:

```
a:not(#flag a) {
   color: red;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: 1+ Nice way to think outside of the box.

Comment: is it compatible with all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

you need to overwrite the global styles, simply making them not apply is not possible.
to overwrite them use something like this

```
#menu a{        
    color: #000;
}
```

//and for hover etc

```
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited, #menu a:active, #menu a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is an a tag in your li you can write somethig like

```
#menu li a {
    color:red;
}
```